# How do you retrieve Django objects from a recursive many to many relationship?

Tags: python, django, recursion, many-to-many

I have a Django class representing articles. Sometimes one article comments on one or more other articles and I have represented this relationship in the class using a recursive many-to-many relationship as follows:

```
class Article(models.Model): 
    comments_on = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)
```

I think that I've successfully associated articles with one another in the admin interface by selecting multiple articles in the comments_on field. Let's say that one article (id1) comments on two other articles (id2 and id3). I don't know how to access the comments_on attribute of id1 so that id2 and id3 appear in my Django template.

I tried:

```
{{ [instance of Article object].comments_on }}
```

but all I get is:

```
[name of my app].Article.None
```

I'd like to know (1) how do I access this attribute and get it to display? And (2) how do I access one of the associated articles at a time? For example, if id1 comments on both id2 and id3, how can I display just id2 or just id3?

Comment: Well comments_on is a M2M field so you'd have to do a for loop over the returned queryset from `Article.comments_on.all()` and display their attributes.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to assign that to a variable in my function in views.py with myvariable = Article.comments_on.all() and then I tried to loop through myvariable in my html file, but I received an AttributeError that said: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: First of all, `Article` is the class name of the model. `Article.comments_on` would return the `ManyToManyDescriptor` function.
You only just need to call `[instance of Article].comments_on.all()` to get the queryset.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your advice. Based on your comments, I solved it as follows:

In views.py, I wrote:

```
myvariable = Article.objects.all()
```

and then passed it to the context dictionary so I could render the variable with the webpage.

On the template, I wrote:

```
{% if item.comments_on.all.count == 1 %}
    {% for key in item.commented_on_by.all %}
      <strong>This study criticized:</strong> <a href="#">{{ key }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
 {% endif%}

  {% if item.comments_on.all.count > 1 %}
    <strong>This study criticized:</strong>
    <ul>
      {% for key in item.comments_on.all %}
        <li><a href="#">{{ key }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif%}
```